# And function in google sheets not working with complex funtions

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

=IF(
K22;
ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
FILTER(
Pockets2.0!A:E;
Pockets2.0!A:A;
REGEXMATCH(Pockets2.0!C:C;"MTC");
K22=Pockets2.0!A:A;
O22=IF(
**AND(REGEXMATCH(Pockets2.0!C:C;"MTC-.*$");TRUE());**
-1;
1
) * Pockets2.0!D:D
);
1;
5
);
)

if I quit the and and just put the first statement it works, but with 'and' and true it fails

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: `and(booleanFunction(), true)` is the same as `booleanFunction()`. Use a less convoluted and _realistic-looking_ example. See [The correct way to publicly share a Google test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `and()` function is an aggregating function and will not give row-by-row results in an array formula the way you seem to expect. To make it work, use [Boolean arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-element_Boolean_algebra), like this:

```
=filter( 
  Pockets2.0!A:E, 
  K22 = Pockets2.0!A:A, 
  regexmatch(Pockets2.0!C:C, "mtc"), 
  O22 = if( regexmatch(Pockets2.0!C:C, "mtc-") * (true = true), -1, 1 ) * Pockets2.0!D:D 
)
```

Comment: You pointed in the right direction, I'll check the boolean arithmetic I intended to add other regex but this simple thing was failing